# Get a report of which buttons a user pressed in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, analytics-events, button

My gambling site has 3 buttons for 3 games (horses, football and dogs) and a final button in order to bet.

I want to know how many buttons game + bet button the users click. I mean, the journey is: to click one, or two or three buttons game and finally, to confirm, the bet button. Every button has an event.

How can I track it via a report in Google Analytics?

Comment: It sounds like you already implemented events for the button, but now you need to figure out how to set up the report in GA?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller yes! it is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can: 
A: Set up custom goals with event category related to each button, so you will have it like a conversions 
B: Just go in to event section filter out categories to include these 4 events only and than drive a conclusion
C: If you wanna track sport + bet, we will need a bit more info: Like when you click on dogs does something happen, does some modal opens, does url change etc. So we can be more accurate with helping.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The idea is to have in the same layout all the buttons, so you can click/unclick one, two or three types of games (football, dogs and/or horses) + place bet button. When you click a button game, it will appear  just like on clicked mode. When you click the place bet button, a message will appear saying you have done the bet correctly.

Comment: Okay, I have just came up with an idea, pretty simple you track the message, you can modify the message a bit (your bet on football / dogs / horses / is accepted or whatever) and than create a custom javascript variable to print out which sport is selected. In that way you will have the most accurate numbers of how many of users actually placed bet with least amount of work and site usage.